# Extract segments from FLV file?

Tags: windows, video, editing

I'm no expert with editing videos, and I need to rip a few segments from an FLV file, and then upload some of them to YouTube. I don't know if I need to convert FLV to AVI for YouTube to accept them.

I've taken a look at VirtualDub + the FLV plug-in but the video isn't displayed correctly. I also tried AviDemux, but I couldn't find how to extract a segment after setting the A/Start and B/End points.

Does someone know of a good solution to do this on Windows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Moyea FLV Editor Lite](http://www.exp-flv.com/flv-editor/).

> Moyea FLV Editor Lite is a free FLV
>   editor especially designed for FLV
>   files. With this editor, you can edit
>   YouTube, MySpace, blogTV, etc. The
>   editor does not recode the FLV files,
>   so it perfectly keeps the original
>   quality. The notable thing is it
>   enables you to edit FLV with timeline
>   to trim FLV video length, split FLV
>   duration, rip FLV audio and video,
>   replace the FLV audio, add cue point
>   and metadata, etc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link. For those having the same issue... I was given the option of downloading an MP4 version (video = avc1, audio mp4a 44KHz). I could succesfully read the output in VLC after ripping a segment with AviDemux (keeping the video as-is but converting audio to MP3 to avoid crappy sound).

Comment: The website is down now, but I could find the installer on cnet: http://de.download.cnet.com/Moyea-FLV-Editor-Lite/3000-2168_4-10912717.html The tool didn't work for me however, seems to be outdated.