# extract a portion of an flv file?

Tags: command-line, flv, video-editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract segments from FLV file?](https://superuser.com/questions/127519/extract-segments-from-flv-file)

I'd like to extract  between for example 5min-8min from an flv file.

Solution should use as minimal amount of RAM as possible.

a command-line is fine, even very good.